# Why my text is centred in Column even I set crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Text in Column]

I want the Column() to start at the very start(left) of the Card(), so I putted my text() in a column, and I have set the crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, set container width to double.infinity, but the text still align in the centre of the container.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance guys.

```
class _ClassCardState extends State<ClassCard> {
  var _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 10,
            right: 10,
            top: 40,
          ),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
              });
            },
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              elevation: 0.3,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      // padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'Yoga (Beginner)',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black87,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 3,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Stretch',
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 3,
                          ),
                          Text('30mins'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    // if (_isExpanded)
                    // TimeSlot(),
                    if (_isExpanded)
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                    if (_isExpanded)
                      Text(
                        'Sheung Wan MAXFIT',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // Positioned(
        //   child: Container(
        //     child: ClipRRect(
        //       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        //       child: Image.asset(
        //         './assets/images/yoga.png',
        //         fit: BoxFit.cover,
        //       ),
        //     ),
        //     height: 118,
        //     width: 90,
        //   ),
        //   left: 30,
        //   top: 15,
        // ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using a container widget for purpose of padding just use the `Padding` Widget itself, and set `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to stretch children of the column, full code below:

```dart
Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10,
                right: 10,
                top: 40,
              ),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
                  });
                },
                child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  elevation: 0.3,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          // padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'Yoga (Beginner)',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black87,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 3,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Stretch',
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 3,
                              ),
                              Text('30mins'),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                        // if (_isExpanded)
                        // TimeSlot(),
                        if (_isExpanded)
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                        if (_isExpanded)
                          Text(
                            'Sheung Wan MAXFIT',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // Positioned(
            //   child: Container(
            //     child: ClipRRect(
            //       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            //       child: Image.asset(
            //         './assets/images/yoga.png',
            //         fit: BoxFit.cover,
            //       ),
            //     ),
            //     height: 118,
            //     width: 90,
            //   ),
            //   left: 30,
            //   top: 15,
            // ),
          ],
        )
```

[image: the output]

Answer (score 0):

Set 
`crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` 
for the first column on line 26

Answer (score 0):

You have two `Column`s in the layout. You also had to add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` to the first `Column`

```
Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
  elevation: 0.3,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Column( // THIS COLUMN NEED crossAxisAlignment
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, 
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            // padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[

//// rest of code
```

[image]